# Docker compose unable to find file in ADD path

Tags: linux, docker, docker-compose

I am using the following docker compose:

```yaml
dns_to_redis:
  build: 
   context: ./DNS_to_redis/
  image: dns_to_redis
  depends_on:
     - redis
  environment:
    - REDIS_HOST=redis
    - REDIS_PORT=6379
  networks:
   sensor:
     ipv4_address: 172.24.1.4
```

to build and run an image. Inside the Dockerfile I use the following ADD:

```
ADD home/new_prototypes/dns_to_redis/dns_redis.R /home/
```

However, when I run `sudo docker-compose up`, I get the following error:

```bash
ERROR: Service 'dns_to_redis' failed to build: ADD failed: file not found in build context or excluded by .dockerignore: stat home/new_prototypes/dns_to_redis/dns_redis.R: file does not exist
```

The file is located in `/home/new_prototypes/dns_to_redis`, I am thinking that this is somehow the problem, but I can't modify it in any way to make it work.

How can I run this from docker compose?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the error message:

> file not found in build context

The [build context](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#understand-build-context) is a copy of the path you set for `dns_to_redis.build.context`.

Your file needs to be in the `./DNS_to_redis/` directory.
Note that it is [generally preferred](https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/#add-or-copy) to use `COPY` instead of `ADD`.